# Slow response from ENC28J60

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I am making a circuit which turns a LED on and off through internet. I am connecting an Arduino to a LED and to an Ethernet controller(ENC28J60), but when I make a `GET` request to the device, it takes too long to respond - around 2 minutes - but my internet connection is fast.Before i get ip "ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac,8)" command fails it returns zero still i am able to control it.

Code:

```
#include <EtherCard.h>

#define STATIC 0

// mac address
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0x31 };
// ethernet interface ip address
static byte myip[] = { 172,26,40,250 };
// gateway ip address
static byte gwip[] = { 172,26,40,1 };

// LED to control output
int ledPin10 = 10;

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];

const char page[] PROGMEM =
"HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
"Retry-After: 600\r\n"
"\r\n"
"<html>"
"<head><title>"
"Service Temporarily Unavailable"
"</title></head>"
"<body>"
"<h3>This service is currently unavailable</h3>"
"<p><em>"
  "The main server is currently off-line.<br />"
  "Please try again later."
"</em></p>"
"</body>"
"</html>"
;

void setup () {
    pinMode(ledPin10, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Trying to get an IP...");

  Serial.print("MAC: ");
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    Serial.print(mymac[i], HEX);
    if (i < 5)
      Serial.print(':');
  }

  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac,8) == 0) 
    Serial.println( "Failed to access Ethernet controller");
  else
    Serial.println("\nEthernet Controller Initialized");


#if STATIC
  Serial.println( "Getting static IP.");
  if (!ether.staticSetup(myip, gwip)){
    Serial.println( "could not get a static IP");

  }
#else

  Serial.println("Setting up DHCP");
  if (!ether.dhcpSetup()){
    Serial.println( "DHCP failed");
  }
#endif

  ether.printIp("My IP: ", ether.myip);
  ether.printIp("GW IP: ", ether.gwip);
  ether.printIp("DNS IP: ", ether.dnsip);
}

void loop () {

  word len = ether.packetReceive();
  word pos = ether.packetLoop(len);


  // IF LED10=ON turn it ON
  if(strstr((char *)Ethernet::buffer + pos, "GET /?LED10=ON") != 0) {
  Serial.println("Received ON command");
  digitalWrite(ledPin10, HIGH);
}

// IF LED10=OFF turn it OFF  
if(strstr((char *)Ethernet::buffer + pos, "GET /?LED10=OFF") != 0) {
  Serial.println("Received OFF command");
  digitalWrite(ledPin10, LOW);
}

// show some data to the user
memcpy_P(ether.tcpOffset(), page, sizeof page);
ether.httpServerReply(sizeof page - 1);
}
```

[image: circuit]